# Не компилируется приложение

Tags: android-studio

при запуске приложения выходит ошибка

> package de.hdodenhof.circleimageview does not exist

и

> cannot find symbol class CircleImageView

не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Вам явно намекают, что файла `de\hdodenhof\circleimageview.java` нет или там что то не так (например, имя класса неверно написано).

Comment: если такой класс/пакет есть, проверьте, нет ли случайно в его имени русских букв "а", "с", "е", "о"

Comment: У вас не подключена или как-то не так подключена вот эта либа: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView Покажите build-gradle в котором описаны зависимости вашего приложения